# Компилятор C++ для DOS-программ реального режима

Tags: c++, dos

Может ли кто-либо ответить на такой вопрос: а какой существует самый современный компилятор C++ для создания программ реального режима под DOS?
Под "самым современным" подразумевается компилятор, поддерживающий наиболее поздний стандарт C++. И какой, собственно, этот стандарт?

Comment: Надо полагать, что ни один из компиляторов под DOS не поддерживает никаких стандартов С++ после С++98. ¿Откуда вообще может взяться современный компилятор под DOS? Ну и сам посыл про ДОС в контексте написания программ реального режима очень странные. Хочется реальный режим - пишите драйвер и загрузчик какой-нибудь.

Comment: Для программ защищённого режима под DOS я использую DJGPP, а это новейший GCC, так что там C++20 и всё в порядке. 
А вот как с реальным режимом? Может быть Open Watcom? Он, вообще, может создавать программы для реального режима? И какой там поддерживается стандарт?

Comment: "под DOS" подразумевает 16-битные приложения

Comment: Нет, под "DOS" - значит все программы, которые работают на платформе DOS. Они могут быть 16-битными, 32-битными, и даже, с недавнего времени, 64-битными. Но да, в данном вопросе предметом являются именно 16-битные программы - программы "реального режима" работы процессора x86.

Comment: Open Watcom C++?

Comment: Итак, вкратце излагаю плоды своих суточных изысканий. Сначала углубился в Open Watcom. Поначалу он вызвал у меня лютый восторг: MZ, NE и PE файлы на выходе (это всё для DOS), для NE и PE есть DLL, отличный отладчик с функцией удалённой отладки по куче различных каналов связи (в DOS это может быть очень важно).

Но вот далее... Какой именно стандарт C++ поддерживает сам компилятор, сказать трудно, но семантики перемещения - нет. Совсем нет.  Правозначных ссылок, следовательно, тоже. Из умных указателей - только auto_ptr. Словом, я так программировать не смогу. Увы...

Comment: Но при раскопках я наткнулся вот на это:
https://sourceforge.net/p/freedos/news/2022/01/ia-16-gcc-toolchain-and-libi86-library-jan-2022-version/
Это вариант GCC с кодогенератором 16-битового кода и стандартной библиотекой C++ для программ DOS реального режима. GCC новейший, поэтому C++20. Библиотека пока не исчерпывающая (кое-чего ещё  не реализовано). Проблемы также с отладчиком - его пока просто нет, так что отладка в исходных текстах пока невозможна.
Но работать уже можно. И даже нужно! Это, по всей видимости, лучшее, что пока есть для DOS реального режима.